# Apache Roller Weblogger Configuration for ORACLE

Tags: java, blogger

I am using **Apache Roller 5.0.1** Weblogger, deploying in **Tomcat6.0.29** with **Oracle** database with all the configration in **roller-custom.properties**.

I am able to login and create a blog. but after creating a blog if i try to access the created blog by the link `**//localhost:8080/roller/blogname**` in the browser but i am getting an **Unexpected Exception**:

```
Status Code: 500 
Message  
Type  
Exception:   Roller has encountered and logged an unexpected exception
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you checked the roller.log file (location defined in roller.properties if not roller-custom.properties), that should point out the specific problem.